# Clustering of Mixed Data using Euclidean distance

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset which contains continues and categorical type of data.

Can anyone help with below questions.

Can i use k-means clustering and euclidean distance or should i use Gower's distance?

When to use euclidean distance/Gower's distance?

How can we know we have formed the correct clusters?

Answer (score 0):

K-means and Euclidean distance are defined on a vector space of real numbers. Thus, **they are not defined on mixed data**. Hence you can't use them, it would not be k-means / Euclidean distance but something different.

There are plenty of alternatives if you do some research in literature.

You *never* know whether you have the "correct" clusters, because there is no such thing as a "right" or "wrong" cluster. It's subjective, not objective.